# Spring: autowired DAO is null in custom UserServiceDetails implementation

Tags: spring, spring-security, autowired

I am configuring the security in my Spring project and unfortunately I encountered a problem. Why is the autowired userDAO in CustomUserDetailsService.java null?

Here is the code in question:

**CustomUserDetailsService.java**

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
@ComponentScan(basePackages="...")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

   @Autowired
   private UserDAO userDAO;

   public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

       // userDAO is null
       UserModel user = userDAO.getUserByUsername(username);
       ...
   }
}
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/login" security="none"/>

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login
        login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/home"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="10" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="... .service.CustomUserDetailsService" />
```

Edit:

**UserDAOImpl.java**

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public UserDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

   public UserModel getUserByUsername(String username) {

       String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + username + "'";

       return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<UserModel>() {

            public UserModel extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
               if (rs.next()) {
                   UserModel user = new UserModel();
                   user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                   user.setPassword(rs.getString("passwort"));
                   user.setEnabled(rs.getBoolean("enabled"));

                   return user;
               }
               return null;
           }
       });
   }
}
```

Here is the code snippet in the Java-based configuration file:

```
@Bean
public UserDAO getUserDAO() {
    return new UserDAOImpl(getDataSource());
}
```

Interesting though, this configuration seems to be sort of working. When I autowire the UserDAO into my controller, it works perfectly fine:

**MainController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"", "/", "/home"})
public String homeHandler(Model model) {

    // userDAO is not null, works perfectly fine and returns the UserModel-Object as expected
    UserModel user = userDAO.getUserByUsername("dx");

    ...
}
```

I already read some Q&A, yet so far it concerned manual instatiation of the custom UserDetailsService. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Is it being scanned?

Comment: The java configuration? Yes, it is. When I testwise autowire the DAO into my main controller (same way as every other DAO), it is not null and works fine (return the user as expected).It is only null in CustomUserDetailsService.java.

Comment: Where does the method `getUserDAO()` exist?

Comment: It is the java configuration file. Yes, my project is both xml and java configured.

Comment: Show your Java config file.. Why need both? Add UserDAO and DataSource to your xml otherwise.

Comment: It is because - to some extent - I based my project on stackoverflow examples, some of which showed xml based conf., while others were based on Java configuration.

Please see my edited question though: The configuration works fine so far. It is only the UserDetailsService implemention which is concerned. The autowired instantiation of UserDAO works in the controller though.

Comment: It cannot be `null` i you have setup annotation correctly, if it is `null` you either are constructing instances yourself (out of control for Spring) or haven't setup annotation processing. Which in your case seems to be the issue add `<context:annotation-config />` to your configuration.

Comment: That is the riddle: It is not null in the controller class, but it is null in the userdetailsservice class. But I think you hinted the correct thing. I am going to check my application configuration and let you know. Thank you so far.

Comment: Doing a `@ComponentScan` at `CustomUserDetailsService` might clean up the previous scanned items from Spring Bean Pool. But still you can access the `UserDAO` from your controller because it is already injected when it gets created via `Configuration`. Anyway I'm not sure about this. You should not do a `@ComponentScan` at a regular component. Either put it into your Java configuration or add to the xml as `<context:component-scan>`.

Comment: Without having `<context:annotation-config />` and/or `<context:component-scan>` in the xml (originally) I'm not sure how your controller gets picked up by spring. You have another xml for mvc configs I guess.

Comment: @sura2k Yes, indeed. I have a separate dispatcher-servlet.xml with the configuration <context:component-scan base-package="... controller"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be because you are instantiating the `customUserDetailsService` in two different places. You have `<bean>` definition for it in your spring-security.xml file as well as you have `@Service` annotation on the class itself. In your `XML` bean definition, you are not injecting the `UserDAO` so that it is null.

You need to streamline your project to clean the bean definition in either java config or XML files (this is not required and you can have XML + java config but then it makes it very confusing as to what is instantiating which bean). You have few options;

1. Remove the XML declaration of `CustomUserDetailsService`. Add `<context:component-scan>` in your XML and add the package names and also remove the `@ComponentScan` from `CustomUserDetailsService`. This will allow spring to scan the packages and register the beans marked with `@Service`, `@Bean`, etc annotations. Make sure your java config class is marked with `@Configuration` annotation.
2. You can Decide to use XML config for all the beans in which case you need to remove the `@Bean`, `@Service`, etc annotations and declare all of them in the spring XML bean definition and make sure each of them has proper dependencies injected.

You definitely need to clean up your bean definitions so correct dependencies are injected.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses. Setu's answer was the most helpful one. Obviously, the problem was indeed the double instantiation. I added `<context:component-scan base-package="... .service" />` and left both annotations `@Service("customUserDetailsService")` and `@ComponentScan(basePackages="...")` in `CustomUserDetailsService` (without `@ComponentScan` it didn't work).